# Comparison of two List<T> and fill missing dates and values with the other

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Model:

```
public class DeviceReadingModel
{       
    public Guid Id { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReadingDateTime { get; set; }
    public double ReadingValue { get; set; }            
}
```

With the model, I create two lists of `List<DeviceReadingModel>`

```
1: List<DeviceReadingModel> readingsList = new();
2: List<DeviceReadingModel> datesList = new();
```

List one is filled with readings between two dates, the second list is filled with all of the available intervals for the period between those two dates and defaulted to zero for it's `ReadingValue` value.

The start and end dates can vary.

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2021,06,01,0,0,0);
 DateTime end = new DateTime((2021,06,2,0,0,0););
 int intervals = ((int)end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes) / 15;
```

I then build a list with all of the dates I need for that period (in this instance 96 intervals).

```
 List<DeviceReadingModel> datesList =new();
 for (int i = 0; i < intervals; i++)
 {
      start = start.AddMinutes(15);
      var r = new DeviceReadingModel
      {
          Id = readings.Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
          ReadingDateTime = start,
          ReadingValue = 0
      };
      datesList .Add(r);  
 }
```

The following shows how the data is.

[image]

I currently use the following to find the missing dates:

```
var query =
 from d in datesList 
 where !(from r in readingsList
 select r.ReadingDateTime)
 .Contains(d.ReadingDateTime)
 select d;
```

I then add this to the readings list with `readingsList.AddRange(query);`.

Is there a better way of doing this, because by rights, using this method means I should now be checking the list again. It feels unsafe!

Comment: I would look into Linq extensions and custom comparer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Are you just trying to copy the items from `datesList` to `readingsList` where there is no current entry for the date? What do you mean by "better"? Why do you think the list should be checked again with the current approach? Also, what is `dateFill`? Is that supposed to be `datesList`?

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. (where there is no current entry for the date?). I'm interested to understand if there are more robust methods to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Why does your code not match your description? What is `dateFill`? What is `readings`? Where are `readingsList` and `datesList`? You say "List One" but isn't that wrong?

Comment: Edited, hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization code gets the `Id` each time through the loop, has a type error (`FirstOrDefault()` returns `Guid?` and isn't compatible with `Guid`) and skips the `start` time (was that intentional?).

```
var defaultId = readingsList.First().Id;
int intervals = (int)end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes / 15;
var datesList = Enumerable.Range(0, intervals + 1)
                          .Select(n => new DeviceReadingModel() {
                                            Id = defaultId,
                                            ReadingDateTime = start.AddMinutes(n * 15),
                                            ReadingValue = 0
                                       });
```

By creating a `HashSet` from the read intervals, you can (much) more efficiently find the missing intervals and add them, assuming the overhead of creating the `HashSet` is worth it (e.g. `readingsList` is sufficiently large):

```
var readingsDateTimeHS = readingsList.Select(l => l.ReadingDateTime).ToHashSet();
readingsList.AddRange(datesList.Where(l => !readingsDateTimeHS.Contains(l.ReadingDateTime)));
```

I assume you don't care about the order of `readingsList` which will have all missing intervals at the end.